# How to show two return values of same function into two labels with Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am new to Objective-C.  I have written a function that returns two values. Now I would like to print it into two separate labels, how I can do it?

```
-(NSString *)abc:(NSInteger)weeks year:(NSInteger)year{

............

return ca , da ;

}
```

and when I call this function like

```
resultLabel1.text = [self abc year:year];  //output show the value of da
```

now I want to show the value of ca into resultLabel1.text and da into resultLabel2.text

is it possible?

Comment: Why the downrate people?

Answer (score 5):

You can only return a **single value** from any method in C and C-derived languages. So you simply need to return a single value that represents both values. You can achieve this by making use of a [NSDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

So make it:

```
-(NSDictionary *)abc:(NSInteger)weeks year:(NSInteger)year{

     NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
           ca, @"object1", 
           da, @"object2", nil];

    return dict;

}
```

Another way is to return an [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html):

```
- (NSArray *)abc:(NSInteger)weeks year:(NSInteger)year {

     NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:da, ca, nil];
     return myArray;
}
```

And you can then use these values as:

```
NSArray *myArray = [self abc:2 year:2004];
textLabel.text = (NSString *)[myArray objectAtIndex:0];
textLabel2.text = (NSString *)[myArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Hello i have used it but its show warning (NSString does not response at objectAtIndex, objective c ) both return value show string so how i can fixed this issue.

Comment: I think you did not change your return type of your method. It is thinking you are returning a NSString which obviously does not respond to objectAtIndex. Make sure you return and receive a NSArray. That object **does** respond to objectAtIndex.

Answer (score 2):

As Jules points out a method can "return" only a single value.  However, you have several options for returning multiple values:

1. Return a pointer to an object, where the object contains multiple values.  The object can be an NSArray, NSDictionary or you own class.  [Jules answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214715/how-to-show-two-return-values-of-same-function-into-two-labels-with-objective-c/7214748#7214748) gave some examples of this.
2. Pass multiple pointers in your parameters, and the method can store results in the object or variable pointed to.  See [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020977/passing-out-parameter/6021053#6021053).
3. Return a struct that has multiple fields.  There's an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6962189/154803).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a NSDictionary to return multiple values from a method. In the dictionary each value is named and referenced by a key. The keys in this example are "ca" and "da" and the values are both a short string of text.

```
-(NSDictionary *) abc: (NSInteger) weeks year:(NSInteger) year {

   NSString* ca = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Week is %d", weeks];
   NSString* da = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Year is %d", year];

   return [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:ca, @"ca", da, @"da", nil];
}
```

Call the method and pick out the returned values with code like this:

```
   NSInteger weekParam = @"52".integerValue;
   NSInteger yearParam = @"2011".integerValue;

   NSDictionary *result = [self abc:weekParam  year:yearParam];

   NSLog(@"ca has value: %@", [result objectForKey:@"ca"]);
   NSLog(@"da has value: %@", [result objectForKey:@"da"]);
```

You log should have the following lines added:

```
ca has value: Week is 52
da has value: Year is 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "return" multiple objects as parameters in a block:

```
- (void)method {
    [self returnMultipleObjectsWithCompletion:^(NSString *firstString, NSString *secondString) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", firstString, secondString);
    }];
}

- (void)returnMultipleObjectsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSString *firstString, NSString *secondString))completion {
    if (completion) {
        completion(@"firstReturnString", @"secondReturnString");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to return an NSArray or NSDictionary with the two values.